# Empty inputstream buffer from TcpSocket

Tags: java, sockets, tcpclient

I need to empty the buffer of a inputstream from TcpSocket connection. 
I tried this:

```
public void emptyReadBuffer(){
    try {
        while((DataInputStream)inFromServer.read()>=0) {}
    } catch (IOException e) {}
}
```

But it waits for some input until the timeout... I just want to empty the buffer because I found that sometimes I read dirty data for previous connection.

Comment: Use `InputStream.available`? (If you also try to use `skip` note that does not necessarily skip the requested number of bytes - you still need to loop or use a `skipFully` from somewhere.) However, this is very unlikely to be the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet will loop forever, until either an exception happens, or the socket closes.

What you want is not possible, depending on your definition of 'buffer'.

If you're talking about the actual buffers on the local hardware (So, the network card, etcetera), you can sort of do this, though the actual specification of java's TCP support don't quite guarantee you can do it. However, this is pointless: A new TCP socket simply does not hold stray bytes from previous connections (it would be a major security leak if it was, so, yes, people would care, a lot, it'd be public information).

So, I assume what you really mean is that you have a single, long-lived TCP connections which is used for multiple 'sessions', and you're still picking up bytes from the previous session.

If the latter is indeed what's going on, your use of the word 'buffer' is misleading. You have no idea WHERE those 'stray bytes' are right now: Perhaps they are still stuck somewhere in a router, or in the middle of a cable across the atlantic. The notion of 'just throw away any bytes that have arrived at the local machine' just won't cover it.

What you really need is a unique message along the lines of 'Hello, this is the start of session ', and then your 'emptyReadBuffer' method should instead be: "ignoreAllUntilStartOfSession(String sessionId)" instead. That CAN be done, and will reliably get rid of the previous session.

What your snippet is trying to do and failing would be best done like so:

```
inFromServer.skip(inFromServer.available());
```

But as I said, this doesn't accomplish anything reliably. You really, really shouldn't do this. It WILL fail to do what you want one day because networks are varied and unreliable.

Comment: I try to better explain, I'm connecting to a tcp thermal printer, in error case the printer will send some tcp data. When my connection is open I can receive this data but if the connection is closed I receved this dirty data at next connection (don't know why, maybe for a bad implementation printer side or too long timeout).